# Spring Exception handlers - using both annotated and xml defined

Tags: java, spring-mvc, exception

I've annotated one of my controllers with `@ExceptionHandler`, in hopes of handling the exceptions for that class within the following method.

We also have a site-wide exception handler defined in XML (`SimpleMappingExceptionResolver`).

The `SimpleMappingExceptionResolver` is still handling exceptions in my controller with an `@ExceptionHandler` annotation.

How can I get the controller specific exception handler to deal with exceptions coming from its controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answered in tremendous depth and clarity [here](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?102713-Spring-Web-MVC-ExceptionHandler-ignore-when-exceptionResolver-in-place):

Basically it says to add the `AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver` manually (adding `SimpleMappingExceptionResolver` causes the Annotation resolver not to be automatically added), and set the order of the two Resolvers.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver" 
      p:order="1" />
```